# Share sparkRDD using apache Ignite

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, ignite

What I implemented is:

```
 val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName(“SharedRDD”).setMaster(“local”)
 val sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
 val sparkRDD = sc.wholeTextFiles("sample.csv", 10)
```

This RDD is cached by IgniteContext

```
val igniteContext = new IgniteContext(sc, “example-shared-rdd.xml”, false)

val sharedIgniteRDD = igniteContext.fromCache[String, String](“cachedIgniteRDD”)
if (sharedIgniteRDD.isEmpty())
sharedIgniteRDD.savePairs(sparkRDD)
```

Now henceforth, if any spark Job need to access this RDD, it need not create a new one instead retrieve it from ignite cache.

```
val RDDfromCache = igniteContext.fromCache[String, String](“CachedIgniteRDD”)
```

sample data of input file

```
25/07/13,11599,CLOSED
25/07/13,256,PENDING_PAYMENT
25/07/13,12111,COMPLETE
25/07/13,8827,CLOSED
25/07/13,11318,COMPLETE
25/07/13,7130,COMPLETE
25/07/13,4530,COMPLETE
25/07/13,2911,PROCESSING
25/07/13,5657,PENDING_PAYMENT
25/07/13,5648,PENDING_PAYMENT
```

I need to call groupByKey() API to do grouping on status column of that input file.

your help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please share what you have done until now in your question

Comment: Are you looking to groupByKey before you save to ignite cache or after you save to ignite cache?

Comment: after I save to ignite cache. Need to apply groupByKey on RDDfromCache whcih is Ignite cache.

Comment: What do you intend to do after you do groupByKey?

Comment: I mentioned in question that "I need to call groupByKey() API to do grouping on status column of that input file."

Comment: I have answered below :) please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of `cache` or `persist` should have avoided from getting `rdd` to be recreated again. And you have options to save `rdds` `in-memory`, `memory-disk`, `serialized`, `deserialized` etc. `IgniteContext` is an alternative to above mentioned solutions.

Its a bit tricky for `groupByKey` on your saved `rdd` in `IgniteContext`, as you have used `wholeTextFile` to read the text file. `WholeTextFile` will generate `Tuple2` rdd of *("path to the text file", "text line*s")

Once you read the saved `rdd` `fromCache` of `IgniteContext`

```
val RDDfromCache = igniteContext.fromCache[String, String](“CachedIgniteRDD”)
```

You can do the following for `groupByKey`

```
val groupedRDD = RDDfromCache.flatMap(x => x._2.split("\n")).map(array => (array.split(",")(2), array)).groupByKey().foreach(println)
```

Output would be

```
(CLOSED,CompactBuffer(25/07/13,11599,CLOSED, 25/07/13,8827,CLOSED))
(PENDING_PAYMENT,CompactBuffer(25/07/13,256,PENDING_PAYMENT, 25/07/13,5657,PENDING_PAYMENT, 25/07/13,5648,PENDING_PAYMENT))
............
..........
..........
```

Comment: I also need date wise sum of amount based on status (Complete, Closed ...) 

Example: 

25/07/2017
11599,CLOSED 
256,PENDING_PAYMENT 
12111,COMPLETE 
26/07/2017
8827,CLOSED 
11318,PENDING_PAYMENT 
7130,COMPLETE  
27/07/2017
2911,PENDING_PAYMENT 
5657,COMPLETE
4530,CLOSED

Comment: That should be another question @Vijay :) and thanks for accepting :)

Answer (score 0):

`wholeTextFiles` puts whole file into a single entry, so it doesn't make a lot of sense to save it in Ignite. You will basically have a distributed cache with one big entry in it. This doesn't provide any advantages.

You should split the file first and save each line as a separate tuple. And then you can save this data in Ignite and use RDD API to process it.